# Reference a todonotes missingfigure?

Tags: cross-referencing, todonotes

I am using the `todonotes` package's `missingfigure` command as placeholders for images that I will add to my document in the future. Is there anyway to `\ref{}` these images? That is, I want to add text like:

```
`This is shown in Figure \ref{OneOfMyMissingFigures}.`
```

Is this possible? I didn't see any way to give it a label in the `todonotes` documentation.

Comment: Can you please mock up a [minimal working example (MWE)](http://goo.gl/dtPzv)?

Answer (score 13, accepted):

The `\label` must be inside o after `\caption` in a `figure` float, so  the only missing element must be `\includegraphics`, temporally replaced with `\missingfigure`. Example:

```
\documentclass{article}
\usepackage{graphicx}
\usepackage{todonotes}
\begin{document}

\section{One}
The figure \ref{nicefigure} is nice, but the missing figure \ref{OneOfMyMissingFigures} will be stunning. 
\section{Two}
Some text 

\begin{figure}[h]
\centering
\missingfigure{\Huge Nice this triangle?}
\caption{Some caption}
\label{nicefigure}
\end{figure}

\section{Three}

Some more text
\begin{figure}[h]
\centering
\missingfigure{\Huge I need the image, now!}
\caption{A missing figure}
\label{OneOfMyMissingFigures}
\end{figure}
\end{document}
```

Comment: Ah it's that easy! I guess assumed it was already in a figure environment. Thanks.